# How to set root view controller for a navigation controller in swift without storyboard id. And navigate to other view Only with viewcontroller name

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried to set root view controller for a navigation controller with viewcontoller name only. But i got only with storyboard id only. Please help me with this

```
let story = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTaskVC")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: what do you want ? You want to go to an xib (without using storyboard) ? @ARULMOORTHY C

Comment: show the code you tried.

Comment: I have an option in Objective to to set a viewcontroller as a rootviewcontroller without using Storyboard or Xib. 

And also we scan navigate one viewcontroller to another UIViewcontroller  with its name only without storyboard id or other. I need this type of code in Swift 4.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it is possible but see if the below helps. 
You will need an identifier "String" to perform a segue/push.
Its a segue identifier not a storyboard identifier so be cautious!

```
//Segue
performSegue(withIdentifier: "Put your segue identifier name here", sender: nil)
```

If you have a storyboard ID then,

```
//Push
let storyID = UIStoryboard(name: "your main storyboard name", bundle:nil)
let someview = storyID.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someview_Controller_name") as! someview_Controller_name

navigationController?.pushViewController(someview_Controller_name, animated: true)
```

Comment: here i am asking to navigate without storyboard segue

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTaskVC")

let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
```